# Dimension error in tensorflow.keras on image fusion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have been working on image-fusion project where my model architecture consists of two branches, each containing a series of convolutional and pooling layers, followed by a concatenation layer and several additional convolutional layers. The purpose of the model is to combine two input images into a single output image that retains the most relevant features from each input image. The code reads in 3 images, preprocesses them, passes them through the model, and saves the resulting fused image. However, there is an error in the code due to a mismatch between the number of input channels and the number of channels expected by the convolutional layers in the model.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
import torchvision

import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, UpSampling2D, Concatenate
from google.colab import files

# Define the convolutional layer
conv_layer = nn.Sequential(
    #take in an input image with 3 RGB color channels and apply 16 filters to produce 16 output feature maps. 
    #Each filter is a 3x3 matrix of weights that is convolved with the input image to extract features
    nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
    nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
)

# Define the self-attention layer
class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()

        self.query_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.key_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.value_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels, kernel_size=1)
        self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))

        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, channels, height, width = x.size()
        
        # Project the inputs to query, key, and value
        proj_query = self.query_conv(x).view(batch_size, -1, width * height).permute(0, 2, 1)
        proj_key = self.key_conv(x).view(batch_size, -1, width * height)

        # Compute the attention scores
        energy = torch.bmm(proj_query, proj_key)
        attention = self.softmax(energy)

        # Apply the attention to the value
        proj_value = self.value_conv(x).view(batch_size, -1, width * height)
        out = torch.bmm(proj_value, attention.permute(0, 2, 1))
        out = out.view(batch_size, channels, height, width)

        # Apply the scaling factor and add to the input
        out = self.gamma * out + x

        return out

# Define the image transformer
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

# Instantiate the self-attention layer
self_att_layer = SelfAttention(32)

# Define the directory path and loop through the images
# directory_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion'
# output_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion/FusionOutput'

images_to_fuse = ['/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion/Source3/lytro-01-A.jpg',
                  '/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion/Source3/lytro-01-B-New.jpg',
                  '/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion/Source3/lytro-01-C-New.jpg']


def extract_feature_maps(images_to_fuse):
  images_fused = []
  for filename in images_to_fuse:
      if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.jpeg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
          # Load the image
          # image = Image.open(os.path.join(directory_path, filename))
          image = Image.open(filename)
          # Transform the image
          image = transform(image).unsqueeze(0)
          # Extract the features using the convolutional layer
          features = conv_layer(image)
          # Apply the self-attention layer to the features
          spatial_features = self_att_layer(features)
          # Save the spatial features to disk
          # output_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.pt'
          # torch.save(spatial_features, os.path.join(output_path, output_filename))
          images_fused.append(spatial_features)
  return(images_fused)

import torch

# Define the U-Net architecture
class UNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()

        # Encoder
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, stride=1, padding=1)

        # Decoder
        self.upconv4 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 2, stride=2)
        self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.upconv3 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 2, stride=2)
        self.conv6 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.upconv2 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 2, stride=2)
        self.conv7 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.upconv1 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 2, stride=2)
        self.conv8 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.final_conv = torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 3, 3, stride=1, padding=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Encoder
        x1 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x2 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv2(x1))
        x3 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv3(x2))
        x4 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv4(x3))

        # Decoder
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv4(x4))
        y = torch.cat([y, x3], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv5(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv3(y))
        y = torch.cat([y, x2], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv6(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv2(y))
        y = torch.cat([y, x1], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv7(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv1(y))
        y = torch.cat([y, x], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv8(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.tanh(self.final_conv(y))

        return y

# Load the feature maps
images_to_fuse = ['/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion/Source3/lytro-01-A.jpg',
                  '/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion/Source3/lytro-01-B-New.jpg',
                  '/content/drive/MyDrive/imageFusion/Source3/lytro-01-C-New.jpg']

feature_maps = extract_feature_maps(images_to_fuse)

# Concatenate the feature maps
x = torch.cat(feature_maps, dim=1)

# Instantiate the U-Net model
model = UNet()

# Generate the fused image
fused_image = model(x)

# Save the fused image
torchvision.utils.save_image(fused_image, 'fused_image.jpg')
```

but when I run it to fuse my images together i got this error below:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-0a2251f274f0> in <cell line: 15>()
     13 
     14 # Generate the fused image
---> 15 fused_image = model(x)
     16 
     17 # Save the fused image

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    457                             weight, bias, self.stride,
    458                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    460                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    461 

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 32, 3, 3], expected input[1, 96, 56, 56] to have 32 channels, but got 96 channels instead
```

I have tried many alternatives 2 of which are

```
Changing line:
self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
to 
self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
and also 
self_att_layer = SelfAttention(32)
to
self_att_layer = SelfAttention(32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the following libraries and functions:

```
tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img
tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array
tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input
tensorflow.keras.models.Model
tensorflow.keras.layers.Input
tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D
tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D
tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout
tensorflow.keras.layers.UpSampling2D
tensorflow.keras.layers.Concatenate
google.colab.files
```

Imported the following libraries and functions:

```
torch
torch.nn
torchvision.transforms
PIL.Image
torchvision
```

Defined the U-Net architecture in the UNet class.

Changed the conv_layer from TensorFlow to PyTorch nn.Conv2d layers.

Changed the transform to PyTorch transforms and added the normalization values for the VGG16 model.

Removed the SelfAttention class instantiation and its usages.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
import torchvision

# import os
# import numpy as np
# from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
# from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
# from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, VGG16
# from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, UpSampling2D, Concatenate
# from google.colab import files

# Define the convolutional layer
conv_layer = nn.Sequential(
    #take in an input image with 3 RGB color channels and apply 16 filters to produce 16 output feature maps. 
    #Each filter is a 3x3 matrix of weights that is convolved with the input image to extract features
    nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
    nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
)

# Define the self-attention layer
class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()

        self.query_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.key_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.value_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels, kernel_size=1)
        self.gamma = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1))

        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, channels, height, width = x.size()
        
        # Project the inputs to query, key, and value
        proj_query = self.query_conv(x).view(batch_size, -1, width * height).permute(0, 2, 1)
        proj_key = self.key_conv(x).view(batch_size, -1, width * height)

        # Compute the attention scores
        energy = torch.bmm(proj_query, proj_key)
        attention = self.softmax(energy)

        # Apply the attention to the value
        proj_value = self.value_conv(x).view(batch_size, -1, width * height)
        out = torch.bmm(proj_value, attention.permute(0, 2, 1))
        out = out.view(batch_size, channels, height, width)

        # Apply the scaling factor and add to the input
        out = self.gamma * out + x

        return out
# Instantiate the self-attention layer
self_att_layer = SelfAttention(32)

# Define the image transformer
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

# Instantiate the self-attention layer
self_att_layer = SelfAttention(32)

# Define the directory path and loop through the images
images_to_fuse = [
    'C:/Users/shm22004/Desktop/misc/New folder/LytroDataset/Triple Series/lytro-01-B.jpg',
    'C:/Users/shm22004/Desktop/misc/New folder/LytroDataset/Triple Series/lytro-01-A.jpg',
    'C:/Users/shm22004/Desktop/misc/New folder/LytroDataset/Triple Series/lytro-01-C.jpg'
]
images_to_fuse = list(set(images_to_fuse))

def extract_feature_maps(image, transform):
    # Load and transform the image
    image = transform(Image.open(image)).unsqueeze(0)
    # Extract features and apply self-attention
    if image.dim() == 3:
        image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    features = self_att_layer(conv_layer(image))
    features = torch.squeeze(features)
    features = features.data.numpy()
    return features

# Define the image transformer
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x.squeeze())
])


# Extract and concatenate the feature maps
feature_maps = []
for image in images_to_fuse:
    features = extract_feature_maps(image, transform)
    feature_maps.append(features)

# Define the U-Net architecture
class UNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, channels):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()

        # Encoder
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, stride=1, padding=1)

        # Decoder
        self.upconv4 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1 )
        self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.upconv3 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv6 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.upconv2 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv7 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.upconv1 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv8 = torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.final_conv = torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 3, 3, stride=1, padding=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Encoder
        x1 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x2 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv2(x1))
        x3 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv3(x2))
        x4 = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv4(x3))

        # Decoder
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv4(x4))
        y = torch.cat([y, x3], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv5(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv3(y))
        y = torch.cat([y, x2], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv6(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv2(y))
        y = torch.cat([y, x1], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv7(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.upconv1(y))
        y = torch.cat([y, x], dim=1)
        y = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv8(y))

        y = torch.nn.functional.tanh(self.final_conv(y))

        return y

x = torch.cat([torch.from_numpy(fm) for fm in feature_maps], dim=1)

# Instantiate the U-Net model
model = UNet(in_channels=32, channels=[32, 64, 128, 256, 512])

# Generate the fused image
fused_image = model(x)
print(fused_image)

# Save the fused image
torchvision.utils.save_image(fused_image, 'fused_image.jpg')
```